# elasticsearch.exceptions.TransportError: TransportError 503: Data too large

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm trying to get the response from ES hitting it from python code but it is showing the below error:

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.TransportError: TransportError(503, u'search_phase_execution_exception', u'[request] Data too large, data for [<agg [POSCodeModifier]>] would be [623327280/594.4mb], which is larger than the limit of [623326003/594.4mb]')
```

If i hit the same code from kibana i get the results but using python i'm getting this error. I'm using aggregation in my code. if someone can explain if i need to set some properties or how to optimise it??
Below is the structure for request i'm sending and if i set start and end date greater than 5 days it gives me the error, otherwise i'm getting the results

```
unmtchd_ESdata= es.search(index='cstore_new',body={'size' : 0, "aggs": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": [
            {
              "match": {
                "CSPAccountNo": store_id
              }
            }
          ],
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "ReportDate": {
                  "gte": start_dt,
                  "lte": end_dt
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ,
    "aggs": {
      "POSCode": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "POSCode",
          "size": 10000
        },
        "aggs": {
          "POSCodeModifier": {
            "terms": {
              "field": "POSCodeModifier",
              "size": 10000
            },
            "aggs": {
              "CSP": {
                "terms": {
                  "field": "CSPAccountNo",
                  "size": 10000
                },
                "aggs": {
                  "per_stock": {
                    "date_histogram": {
                      "field": "ReportDate",
                      "interval": "week",
                      "format": "yyyy-MM-dd",
                      "min_doc_count": 0,
                      "extended_bounds": {
                        "min": start_dt,
                        "max": end_dt
                      }
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                      "avg_week_qty_sales": {
                        "sum": {
                          "field": "TotalCount"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "market_week_metrics": {
                    "extended_stats_bucket": {
                      "buckets_path": "per_stock>avg_week_qty_sales"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }

          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}},request_timeout=1000)
```

**Edit1:**
**Result variables needed from elastic search response**

```
for i in range(len(unmtchd_ESdata['aggregations']['filtered']['POSCode']['buckets'])):
            list6.append(unmtchd_ESdata['aggregations']['filtered']['POSCode']['buckets'][i]['POSCodeModifier']['buckets'][0]['CSP']['buckets'][0]['market_week_metrics']['avg'])
            list7.append(unmtchd_ESdata['aggregations']['filtered']['POSCode']['buckets'][i]['key'])
            list8.append(unmtchd_ESdata['aggregations']['filtered']['POSCode']['buckets'][i]['POSCodeModifier']['buckets'][0]['CSP']['buckets'][0]['market_week_metrics']['max']-unmtchd_ESdata['aggregations']['filtered']['POSCode']['buckets'][i]['POSCodeModifier']['buckets'][0]['CSP']['buckets'][0]['market_week_metrics']['min'])
            list9.append(unmtchd_ESdata['aggregations']['filtered']['POSCode']['buckets'][i]['POSCodeModifier']['buckets'][0]['CSP']['buckets'][0]['market_week_metrics']['max'])
            list10.append(unmtchd_ESdata['aggregations']['filtered']['POSCode']['buckets'][i]['POSCodeModifier']['buckets'][0]['CSP']['buckets'][0]['market_week_metrics']['min'])
```

Comment: In Kibana, do you also have size = 10000 for `POSCodeModifier` and `CSP`?

Comment: yes. now kibana also gave the same error. dont know how it worked for the first time. so how to fix it??

Comment: reduce the size

Comment: i reduced. it worked but it will filter a lot of documents for me  which i don't think will be an optimal solution @Val

Comment: Well, feel free to explain your context in a bit more details and why you need that many terms to begin with.

Comment: I actually need some variables reading JSON response which i can directly get from ES aggregations otherwise i need to perform them in python using dataframes. Those variables are max,min,avg over a week period @Val

Comment: Ok, but why do you need to get 10000 X 10000 terms back?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169060/discussion-between-codaholic-and-val).

Comment: 10000 is just a number it's not the upper bound for distinct poscodes. the actual number will be much less most of the times. @Val

Comment: I'm curious to know what the cardinality of `POSCodeModifier` and `CSP` are.

Comment: POSCodeModifier  max will be  50  and CSP will be 500 @Val

Comment: Then there is no need to use size: 10000, use the more accurate figures

Comment: but how will it make a difference because the sample of data it works on will still remain same even if I set accurate figures or am I missing some information about how elasticsearch works? @Val